# Breeze: How do I force a refresh of an entity in cache

Tags: caching, refresh, breeze, hottowel

How can I force the cache to update?

I have an entity that is actually a view in the database. I want force the cached entity to edit. Generally, when saving an entity,  the cache is updated as well. But in this case, I  cannot save the entity as it is a view. I therefore want to force the cache to refresh and read the updated values from the database.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requery for the entity with a MergeStrategy of OverwriteChanges. Something like.

```
var entityKey = myEntity.entityAspect.getKey();
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
    .using(MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges);
myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(...);
```

After the promise resolves the latest version of the entity will be in cache.

Comment: Thank you. This is supposed to generate an http request to get the new set of data, right? I am using chrome developer tool to check request been made to ensure that the request is actually sent, but I cannot see any request made.

Comment: Yes, it will generate a HttpRequest, not sure why you are not seeing it. Is the entity getting updated?

Comment: No. The entity I am trying to update is a lookup. The lookup is created as described here http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/lookup-lists. Therefore, it is created alongside other entities (look ups). If I use the code you provided, will breeze make the HttpRequest for my LookUp method in the controller, although I am only refreshing a single entity? Or am i not supposed to declare the lookuplist this way?

Comment: The code above should work regardless; it doesn't matter how the entity was retrieved in the first place as long as it is an entity and is in the EntityManager. If you are not seeing an HttpRequest my guess is that an exception is being thrown at some point and you are not seeing it.

Comment: Does not work for me, please see my "answer" for more details.

Comment: Yea, the entity isn't in the database anymore but the query still comes up with the entity.  From cache I guess? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Jay's suggestion works but there's a slightly easier way too ... `EntityQuery.fromEntities`:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.fromEntities(myEntity)
    .using(myEntityManager).execute().then(...);
```

If you want to overwrite possible pending changes to `myEntity`, add the OverwriteChanges as Jay did:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.fromEntities(myEntity)
    .using(breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges)
    .using(myEntityManager).execute().then(...);
```

If you want to refresh a bunch of entities (**all of the same type**) you can do that too:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.fromEntities(employees) // employees is an array of Employee entities
    .using(breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges)
    .using(myEntityManager).execute().then(...);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is supposed to generate an http request to get the new set of data, right? I am using chrome developer tool to check request been made to ensure that the request is actually sent, but I cannot see any request made.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work? We've got tests that show it does. Can you repro in a jsFiddle or plunker?